# How can I download a .deb package using curl and update the apt-get repository to install it using apt-get install

Tags: apt-get

I need to download a .deb file using curl command and then update the local repository as in /etc/apt/sources.list , so that I can install the ,deb file through apt-get install ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the entry manually to the sources.list or use add-apt-repository

Comment: I actually want something like curl -L https://linkto package|sudo echo" " >>/etc/apt/sources.list? Will this work?

Comment: Try it, just change **sources** to **sources2** and check your output